# Implementing a custom joint in Box2D

Tags: box2d, joints

I would like to implement a "rail joint" in Box2D: a joint which lets a body move only along a given curve.

I couldn't find anything about defining custom joints. Is it possible at all without forking the engine? Has anyone done it? Where can I find an example or a tutorial? Are there other ways to achieve this?